# Проблемы при нажатии на button и отображении графика.

Tags: c#

В `userControl` осуществляется вывод синусоиды на экран с помощью `pictureBox`.
Реализуемый код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        F = 67000;
        n_pd = 9;
        F_DISCR = 6650000;

            Сигнал SIN = Форм_Син.G_sin(F, n_pd, F_DISCR);

            userControl11.Length = SIN.size;
            for (int i = 0; i < SIN.size; i++)
            {
                userControl11.x[i] = i / F_DISCR;
                userControl11.y[i] = SIN[i];
            }
    }
```

При нажатии на кнопку поле `pictureBox` остается чистым. Но если прикрыть проект и снова расправить, то график появляется. Также после нажатии на кнопку(поле пустое) если подвигать папкой по `pictureBox`, то где папка проехалась там график появляется. Представлено на рисунке.[image]

Как можно исправить данную проблему?

Сделал перерисовку, но вопрос:

```
for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
        {
            y_1 = -y[i];
            y_1_pix = k * (y[i] - y_min) + height;
            x_1_pix = d * (x[i] - x_min) - 1;
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, (float)x_0_pix,(float)y_0_pix (float)x_1_pix, (float)y_1_pix);
            x_0_pix = x_1_pix; y_0_pix = y_1_pix;
        }
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
        public void P_ka()
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
```

Почему первый  **pictureBox1.Invalidate();** не срабатывает, а  **pictureBox1.Invalidate();** в методе **public void P_ka()** работает (т.е. перерисовывает)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень дружу с C#, но рискну предположить, что после рисования, вам нужно вызвать функцию перерисовки поля. Она же принудительная перерисовка: `pictureBox.Invalidate();`

Answer (score 2):

Проблему можно исправить перерисовкой клиентской области. Фактически, когда сворачиваешь-разворачиваешь окно - это происходит, тебе нужно рейзить в ручную это, если меняются данные/масштаб и т.д. Если не ошибаюсь, то вызывается перерисовка через методы [Control.Invalidate (и его производные)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Все рисование должно быть выполнено при вызове ф-и `OnPaint`. Перегрузите вызов данной ф-и для вашего класса. Не забывайте вызывать `Invalidate` для вашего контрола, когда необходима перерисовка.